# remove .php extension from url for only 1 page

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

my url is **http://abcd.com/abc.php**

I want it **http://abcd.com/abc**

I want to do this only for this particular page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need these 2 rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(abc)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^(abc)/?$ /$1.php [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

create an `.htaccess` file (or add this to the existing one):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^abc$ /abc.php [L]
```

then upload to your website root directory.